# Mongoose fetching data, setting in a list (undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch all messages of two users from MongoDB using a custom  function. I am not able to set list. I have no idea how to use callback here.

```
 fetchall = function(chatuser, me)  {
       var allmessage = [] ;
        var promise =  this.model.find({},function(err, docs)  {
          if (err) { return console.error(err); 
            }
             console.log(docs); //working
            //  doSomethingElse(docs);
            allmessage = JSON.stringify(docs);
            return allmessage;
        }).exec();

     // promise.then(doSomethingElse(cc));
        console.log('all',allmessage);   // undefined
        return allmessage;
     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here is Example

```
  fetchall = function(chatuser, me, cb) {
            var allmessage = [];
            var promise = this.model.find({}, function(err, docs) {
                    if (err) {
                        // here cb is callback
                        return cb(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log(docs); //working
                        if (Array.isArray(docs) && docs.length > 0) {
                            // do it here                      
                            cb(null, docs)

                        } else {

                            // throw error here
                           // no result found like
                            cb()
                        }

                    }).exec();

            };
```

Comment: i am calling above function from another class.
cb:any;

const chattCtrl = new ChattCtrl();
chattCtrl.fetchall(m,s,this.cb);

how i should call this function with param cb ??

TypeError: cb is not a function

Comment: you can call the function like this `chattCtrl.fetchall(m,s,function(err, result){ if(err){//do somthing}})`

Comment: it is working now .thank you so much for  helping me.
i have got the result . but how to set this in a list

Comment: Please ask new question on stack overflow